# How IR Remote Control Apps Work?

Tags: java, android, infrared

After a lot of searching, I couldn't find anything useful at all! Example of such app is this: [IR Universal Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freeiruniversalremote)

I am amazed at app because it also controls my old CRT TV. Controls air conditioner, projector etc. Does almost all types of job. I tried searching how could I do the same but no luck. Could you guys please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are building it in android, you would be developing for phones that have to have an IR blaster. 
To control the IR take a look at this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager.html

Additionally you would need access to a database of IR codes that manufacturers use. This is a good place to start: http://lirc.sourceforge.net/remotes/

Edit: So your workflow would be something like this: Get the codes from the repo and use the IR blaster from the phone to control a device.

Comment: Is there any world wide organization that maintains IR codes of all devices?